# Matlab's parpool: How to specify directory for temp files?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, temporary-files

On [this website](https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/it-services/running-multiple-matlab-jobs-at-the-same-time), it states that if one is working on an object of `parcluster`, one can use the property `JobStorageLocation` to modify the directory for temporary files.

It seems the same is not working for `parpool`, and from the [docs](https://de.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parpool.html), I cannot find a similar property name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That document is referring to setting up the `JobStorageLocation` for the ["local" (aka "Processes") cluster type](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/program-independent-jobs-on-a-local-cluster.html#bq5nt83-2). You can use this together with `parpool` like so:

```matlab
c = parcluster("local");
c.JobStorageLocation = "/some/temporary/directory";
parpool(c); % Stores files in /some/temporary/directory
```

Note that this only configures where the files are stored for managing execution of the job. If you want to change the temporary directory used by MATLAB itself, see [this MATLAB Answer](https://uk.mathworks.com/support/search.html/answers/388570-how-can-i-change-the-temp-directory-the-matlab-installer-uses.html) for details.